# iOS tab bar issue when the app is opened with in-call status bar enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios10

When I start the app with in-call status bar already enabled, my tab bar is showing only half. Remaining half is cut out and not seen. And when I disable the in-call status bar, I see black portion above the navigation bar.
There is no issue when the app is already on and I enable the in-call status bar.
How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to correct it by adding this code into my `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
    //hack to fix bug/issues with in-call statusbar braking view constraints
    for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
        if type(of: window).self.description().contains("UITextEffectsWindow") {
            window.removeConstraints(window.constraints)
        }
    }
}
```